# deleting selector without styles causes issue (including header for strping table)

Tags: css

Why does deleting selector without styles include header for striping table? How can deleting empty selector can affect anyithing at all?

Here's css:

```
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0">

TABLE.spreadsheet //if we delete this selector  useless header becomes striped  too
{   
} //this selector seems useless at all


TABLE.spreadsheet TH
{
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 0px 3px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}

TABLE.spreadsheet TD
{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    padding: 0px 3px;
    font-size: 14px;        
}

TABLE.spreadsheet .odd
{
  background-color: #ffefd5;        
}
```

Here is table:

```
<table class="spreadsheet" cellspacing = "0">
        <tr>
           <th></th>
           <th>Email Address</th>
           <th>First Name</th>
           <th>Last Name</th>
           <th>Date</th>
           <th>Phone</th>
           <th>Action</th>          
        </tr>
        <tr>            
                                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="bulk_select[]" id="bulk_select" value="2449831" class="bulk_select"></td>  

                                                        <td>test@gmail.com</td>

                                                        <td></td>

                                                        <td></td>

                                                        <td></td>

                                                        <td></td>


                <td>                        <a href="/lists/edit-subscriber?id=2449831">edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <a href="/lists/delete-subscriber?id=2449831" class="del_subscriber">delete</a></td>                            
            </tr>
                    <tr>            
                                                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="bulk_select[]" id="bulk_select" value="2449880" class="bulk_select"></td>  

                                                        <td>test48@gmail.com</td>

                                                        <td>Mark</td>

                                                        <td>Johnson</td>

                                                        <td></td>

                                                        <td></td>


                <td>                        <a href="/lists/edit-subscriber?id=2449880">edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <a href="/lists/delete-subscriber?id=2449880" class="del_subscriber">delete</a></td>                            
            </tr>
                    <tr>            
                                                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="bulk_select[]" id="bulk_select" value="2449881" class="bulk_select"></td>  

                                                        <td>test49@gmail.com</td>

                                                        <td>Chad</td>

                                                        <td>Davis</td>

                                                        <td></td>

                                                        <td></td>


                <td>                        <a href="/lists/edit-subscriber?id=2449881">edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <a href="/lists/delete-subscriber?id=2449881" class="del_subscriber">delete</a></td>                            
            </tr>

</table>
```

javascript to striping table:

```
    $("table.spreadsheet tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
```

Comment: `$("table.spreadsheet. tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");` there should not be a `.` after spreadsheet

Comment: Yes, that's true, I correct it. But the issues still remains.

Comment: You have css styling directly inside the body, they should be inside a `<style>` tag or in a .css file. Also for future, show us the outputted html code, not the php, as this is not a php question

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean? I still don't understand what's the issue.

Comment: I'll put it in an answer as I think it will resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your styles inside the body tag at the minute like:

```
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0">
TABLE.spreadsheet  {   
}
```

They should be inside a `<style>` tag like so:

```
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0">

<style>
TABLE.spreadsheet  {   
} 

...

</style>
```

My best guess would be that the reason the first selector breaks it if you remove it is because it is acting like the `<style>` tag as you aren't telling the browser that it is a style

Comment: Yes, in the beginning of css I added instead of body: body
{
  margin: 0;
} And then deleted TABLE.spreadsheet {   
} It seems it solves the issue.

Comment: I think style for th helpls to override color of .odd in row with headers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I totally understand your question but if I do is it that you want to add the "odd" class to table cells that aren't in the table header?

If so then do this:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th></th>
  </tr>
 </head>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

$("table.spreadsheet tbody tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
```

Additionally I'd suggest removing those margin tags from the BODY element and using CSS for those.

Also you should move your CSS into a seperate stylesheet and NOT have it within the BODY tag. If you must have it on the page then place it within the HEAD tag within a STYLE tag.

Lastly, instead of this:

```
TABLE.spreadsheet .odd
{
 background-color: #ffefd5;        
}
```

I'd do this:

```
.odd
{
 background:#ffefd5;        
}
```

Comment: I deleted body tag from css, I didn't notice it. It seems after that it seems deleting this select doesn't cause issue any more.

Comment: I light of what you said it makes me think why I don't have header striped as other table, with my layout without tbody and javascript.